# Stored procedure get data from query SET-based

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, set-based

Hello I am making a stored procedure and I am having problem outputting the code with a print because later on i need to write the variables to a temp database. 
This is the code:

```
SELECT 
    fmsTotalAmount + fmsAirTotalAmount + fmsProjectsTotalAmount TotalAmount, 
    fmsRelationAmount + fmsAirRelationAmount + fmsProjectsRelationAmount TotalRelationAmount
    FROM (

        SELECT 
            SUM(
                CASE WHEN fms1.currency != 'EUR' 
                    THEN fms1.Amount * fms1.Rate
                    ELSE ISNULL(fms1.Amount, 0) END) fmsTotalAmount,
            SUM(
                CASE WHEN fms1.relationcode = 'SHIP02' 
                    THEN 
                        CASE WHEN fms1.currency != 'EUR' 
                            THEN fms1.Amount * fms1.Rate
                            ELSE ISNULL(fms1.Amount, 0) END
                    ELSE 0 END) fmsRelationAmount,
            SUM(
                CASE WHEN fmsAir1.currency != 'EUR' 
                    THEN fmsAir1.Amount * fmsAir1.Rate
                    ELSE ISNULL(fmsAir1.Amount, 0) END) fmsAirTotalAmount,
            SUM(
                CASE WHEN fmsProjects1.relationcode = 'SHIP02' 
                    THEN 
                        CASE WHEN fmsProjects1.currency != 'EUR' 
                            THEN fmsProjects1.Amount * fmsAir1.Rate
                            ELSE ISNULL(fmsProjects1.Amount, 0) END
                    ELSE 0 END) fmsAirRelationAmount,
            SUM(
                CASE WHEN fmsProjects1.currency != 'EUR' 
                    THEN fmsProjects1.Amount * fmsAir1.Rate
                    ELSE ISNULL(fmsProjects1.Amount, 0) END) fmsProjectsTotalAmount,
            SUM(
                CASE WHEN fmsProjects1.relationcode = 'SHIP02' 
                    THEN 
                        CASE WHEN fmsProjects1.currency != 'EUR' 
                            THEN fmsProjects1.Amount * fmsProjects1.Rate
                            ELSE ISNULL(fmsProjects1.Amount, 0) END
                    ELSE 0 END) fmsProjectsRelationAmount
        FROM   [fms].[dbo].[file] f
        LEFT JOIN [fms].[dbo].[outgoinginvoiceline] fms1 ON 
            fms1.filenumber = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, f.filenumber)
        LEFT JOIN [fmsAir].[dbo].[outgoinginvoiceline] fmsAir1 ON 
            fmsAir1.filenumber = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, f.filenumber)
        LEFT JOIN [fmsProjects].[dbo].[outgoinginvoiceline] fmsProjects1 ON 
            fmsProjects1.filenumber = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, f.filenumber)


) a
```

Now i want to print the output of this SELECT statement. But when i do this:

> print 'Total money invoiced: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, fmsTotalAmount) + '€ for this Relation'
>       print 'Total money invoiced: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,  fmsTotalRelationAmount) + '€ in total'

But then i get the following error:

> The name "fmsTotalAmount" is not permitted in this context. Valid
>   expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some
>   contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
>
> The name "fmsTotalRelationAmount" is not permitted in this context.
>   Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some
>   contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

On the prints. How do I get the values from this into a variable? Instead of it returning it as a row. I need the variables.

Comment: OT: [Read about a *bad habit to kick*: Declaring (N)VARCHAR without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: I do not understand your goal: If you just **read** data, why are you creating a *stored procedure* (which is meant **to do** something)? What is wrong with a row? What is better with *variables* (especially when the title carries *set-based*)? Please provide some more details!

Comment: The procedure is way bigger then this. And it reads much more data then just this. And it then writes it off to a database

Comment: Thank you, thats all i wanted, i didn't know about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to store the result of a `SELECT` into a table.

To achieve this, you try to write the values into variables first and then - in a second step - you try to insert these variables into a table with an `INSERT` statement.

Better was to try this syntax:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... INTO #SomeTable FROM SomeWhere
```

The `INTO #SomeTable` will create a temp table with the fitting structure automatically and insert the full result into this newly created temp table.

A simple `SELECT * FROM #SomeTable` would bring back the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare a printvariable first and print that value.

```
declare @ptext varchar(max)
select @ptext = 'Total money invoiced: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, fmsTotalAmount) + '€ for this Relation' 
print @ptext
select @ptext = 'Total money invoiced: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, fmsTotalRelationAmount) + '€ in total'
print @ptext
```